# offline: Authorization response did not include a principalId: (λ: authorize) in aws lambda using node serverless offline

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-offline

I am new to node and AWS lambda, I want to run all API endpoints locally so  I am hitting a protected route with all valid credentials, but still getting this error.

offline: Authorization response did not include a principalId: (λ: authorize) ,

any solutions?

Comment: Hello,
Have you found a solution to this?  I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @RyanCarville Yes, I was passing an incorrect variable to generate the policy method, in the response that I got the above error, I solved it by error handling and passing valid principleId(in my case its an userToken{UUID})to generate policy method